# JQuery get formaction and formmethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the a like this one

```
<form id="popisgolubova_form">
    <input name="pregledaj" type="button" formaction="uredigoluba.php" formmethod="post" formtarget="_self" value="pregledaj" class="button" onclick="popisgolubova_radiobutton(this)">
    <input name="rodovnik" type="button" formaction="rodovnik.php" formmethod="post" formtarget="_blank" value="rodovnik" class="button" onclick="popisgolubova_radiobutton()">
    <input name="podaci" type="button" value="poodaci" formaction="podaciogolubu.php" formmethod="post" formtarget="_blank" class="button" onclick="popisgolubova_radiobutton()">
</form>
```

and javascript

```
function popisgolubova_radiobutton(element)
{
    alert($(element).find("[formaction]").val());
    var popisgolubova_radiobutton=$("input[name=RadioGroup1]").is(":checked");
    if(popisgolubova_radiobutton==false)
    {
        alert("nop");
    }
    else
    {
        $("form#popisgolubova_form").submit();
    }   
}
```

First I'm checking if any checkbox is checked or not and if it is the I can submit the form. But the problem is formaction, formmethod and formtarget. how to get them and submit them

Comment: Your html markup is wrong, where is the checkbox? sounds like `html` is from other page and 'script` is from other page.

Comment: I left out checkboxes because it is working so I just left them out. I need answer how to get that formaction

Answer (score 12):

To get the action or method attributes of a form you can try something like below:

```
$(function() { 
    var action = $("#formid").attr('action'),
        method = $("#formid").attr('method');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is going to work cause I need to get formaction and formmethod from that button, not from whole form

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps to get an idea to solve ur problem

```
<form id="popisgolubova_form">
<input name="pregledaj" type="button" formaction="uredigoluba.php" formmethod="post" formtarget="_self" value="pregledaj" class="button postForm"/>
</form>

$(document).on('click', '.postForm', function () {

$('#popisgolubova_form').attr('action', $(this).attr('formaction'));
$('#popisgolubova_form').attr('method', $(this).attr('formmethod'));
$('#popisgolubova_form').attr('formtarget', $(this).attr('formtarget'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So the question is talking about the unfortunately named

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction

...which is a way to override

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action

per clicking a properly set up submit button. The place you want to check this is upon submit - when you're sure things are actually being submitted.

The button you used to submit is stored as :focus - this does not seem to be otherwise stored in the event object at the moment.

```
$('form').on("submit", function(event) {
  if( $(':focus').is('[formaction]') ) {
    console.warn($(':focus').attr('formaction'));
    }

  if( $(':focus').is('[formtarget]') ) {
    console.warn($(':focus').attr('formtarget'));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $(':focus').is('[formaction]') ) {
    console.log($(':focus').attr('formaction'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after searching the web I couldn't find a proper answer. Finally, I realized it's so simple.

When you add an event on `form.submit` you have an event argument that contains `e.originalEvent.submitter`, just use it as follows:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var url = form.attr('action');
    if (e.originalEvent.submitter) {
        var frmAction = $(e.originalEvent.submitter).attr('formaction');
        if (frmAction)
            url = frmAction;
    }
    ,.....
});
```

You can use the samething for the `formmethod` as well.